# Matlab's Princomp command- is it non-negative definite or not?

Tags: matlab, pca, princomp

In Matlab, while trying to do PCA, is there a difference when using the princomp command for positive vs. negative data values? Is it a non-negative definite command? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The condition of non-negative defininiteness in PCA does not refer to the data (that wouldn't make sense) but to the covariance matrix estimated from the data. `princomp` estimates the covariance matrix internally from your data, and such an estimate is always guaranteed to be non-negative definite, no matter what you data look like.

Comment: You can use prcomp(), that uses SVD, instead of princomp(), that uses eigenvalues of the covariance matrix